# Component doesn't get destroyed when *ngIf is false

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a component with the following child component:

```
<app-fullscreen *ngIf="displayFullscreen" [images]="images" [selected]="selected" 
(fullscreenChange)="closeFullscreen($event)"></app-fullscreen>
```

When someone clicks on one of my images, this methods gets called:

```
openFullscreen(images: any, img: any) {
 this.images = images;
 this.selected = img;
 this.displayFullscreen = true;
}
```

Now the component is displayed. Once `displayFullscreen` is set to false again, the `app-fullscreen` component does not get destroyed. I noticed this in the DOM:

[image]

So it detects that the `ngIf` is now false, but it does not do anything about it. How do I make the component disappear?

Edit: Information about how I'm setting `displayFullscreen` to false.

In the `app-fullscreen` child component, I emit an event with the value "false":

```
closeFullscreen(){
  this.fullscreenChange.emit("false");
}
```

When the event is emitted, the parent component calls this method:

```
closeFullscreen(event: any){
  this.displayFullscreen = event;
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

As you can see I even tried calling `detectChanges()` but that did not help.

Comment: Post the relevant code. There's a bug in it.

Comment: You should add the code and explanation of where displayFullScreen is set to false. This is crucial information to help you as the change detection cycle  is involved

Comment: @ivissani I have added the code that you have requested. If you need more let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You emit the string `"false"`. The string `"false"` is truthy. So the `ngIf` still displays the component.

Use booleans for boolean values, not strings.

Comment: Oh man, I tried with a boolean value at first, but it said that a string or symbol was required. Turned out I had imported  `EventEmitter` from `events` instead of `@angular/core` and then it didn't cross my mind to try with a boolean value again after correcting that. Anyway, thanks a lot.